# seeing every interaction as a conflict

Tags: diagnosis

What could cause someone to see every interaction/conversation as a battle that they have to win. whether it be with strangers or close family members, including their children, and they have to 'win' regardless of the physical, emotional or financial cost to themselves or the person they are interacting with, even if it is entirely out of proportion.

Is there a name for this type of behaviour ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [Unilateral Control Model of Behaviour](https://books.google.co.uk/books?hl=en&lr=&id=9eHf_QoGY1MC&oi=fnd&pg=PA33&dq=unilateral%20control&f=false#v=onepage&q=unilateral%20control&f=false).  The opposite is "Give Up Control Model" and in the middle, you have "Mutual Learning".  You can see another copy of Unilateral Control's definition [here](http://www.schwarzassociates.com/managing-performance/how-unilateral-control-undermines-team-results-and-relationships-2/).

> Having goals is essential to being effective as an individual, team, and organization. But when you use a unilateral control mindset, you see challenging situations as a contest in which there are winners and losers.